# How to handle array values in react-hook-form custom component

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, react-typescript

I have a form that uses react-hook-form's Controller type to pass the field and ref into a custom component that is meant to display an array of checkboxes. All the selected checkboxes become elements in an object array, representing the field value.

This is the component i have made:

```ts
type FormCheckBoxesParts = {
  options: Quality[]; onChange: (...event: any[]) => void; value: Quality[] | undefined; name: string; ref: Ref<Array<Quality>>;
}
const handleTraitCheck = (value: Spec[], checkedName: Spec) => {
  const existingValue = value.filter(qi => qi.name === checkedName.name);
  if (existingValue && existingValue.length === 1) {
    // then we are unchecking, so remove element from value array
    value.splice(value.indexOf(existingValue[0]),1)
  } else {
    // then we are checking, so add element from value array
    value.push(checkedName);
  }  
};


export const SpecArrayCheckboxes: FunctionComponent<FormCheckBoxesParts> = forwardRef(({ onChange, value, name, options }, ref) => {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={strikerTheme}>
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      {
        options.map((option: Quality) => {
          return (
            <Tooltip title={option.description}>
              <FormControlLabel
                ref={ref}
                key={option.name}
                label={option.name}
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={value && value.some((fo: Quality) => fo.name === option.name)}
                    onChange={() => value && onChange(handleTraitCheck(value, option))}
                  />
                }
              />

            </Tooltip>
          );
        })
      }
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
});
```

and the form that is referencing it (its part of a tabbed set of forms):

```ts
export const DescriptionForm = ({
  onSubmit,
  data
}: {
  data: Partial<Char>;
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Partial<Char>>;
}) => {

  const {
    specState
  } = useAppSelector(state => state);
  
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      ...data,
    }
  });

  const alignments = ['Lawful Good', 'Neutral Good', 'Chaotic Good', 'Lawful Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Chaotic Neutral', 'Lawful Evil', 'Neutral Evil', 'Chaotic Evil']
  const traits: Quality[] = getTraits(specState.specKeys);
  const ideals: Quality[] = getIdeals(specState.specKeys);

  return (

    <ThemeProvider theme={strikerTheme}>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <div className='form-row'>
          <Controller name="name" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField sx={{ width: '40ch' }} {...field} label="character name" />} />
        </div>
        <div className='form-row'>
          <Controller name="experience" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="experience" />} />
          <Controller name="levels" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="level" />} />
        </div>
        <div className='form-row'>
          <Controller name="age" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="age" />} />
          <Controller name="gender" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="gender" />} />
          <Controller name="height" control={control} render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="height" />} />
          <Controller name="weight" control={control} render={({ field }) => 
            <TextField {...field} label="weight" InputProps={{
              endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">kg</InputAdornment>,
            }}
            />} 
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-row'>
        <Controller
        name="alignment"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} label="alignment" helperText="Please select your alignment" select>
          {alignments.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
              {option}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>}
        />
        <div className='form-row'>
          
          <Controller name="traits" control={control} render={({ field }) => <SpecArrayCheckboxes
            {...field}
            options={traits}/>
          } />
        </div>

        <div className='form-row'>
           
          <Controller name="ideals" control={control} render={({ field }) => <SpecArrayCheckboxes
            {...field}
            options={ideals}/>
           } />
        </div>

        </div>
        <button
          type='submit'
          className='btn btn-block btn-danger'
        >
          Submit
        </button>

      </form>
    </ThemeProvider>

  )
};
```

as you can see, its the last two Controllers: "traits" and "ideals" that is referencing the custom component.

Essentially, everything displays as expected, but I can't seem to get the form to hold onto the values selected by the checkboxes. I.e., if you check a box, presumably the handleTraitCheck method is run, the form is refreshed, and the check on the checkbox disappears.

So I'm not sure how to pass the value references in, nor how to set the values, and, finally how to retain them (i have spent hours looking at various stackoverflow answers, and yet i still don't have a clear idea on this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have (sort of) figured it out.

After trying loads of different approaches, the following component, seems to be doing the right things:

```ts
import Checkbox, { CheckboxProps } from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import ThemeProvider from "@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider";
import { strikerTheme } from "../../../shared/components/StrikerTheme";
import { Quality, Spec } from "../../models/specs";
import { Char } from "../../models";
import { Ref, forwardRef } from "react";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import { UseControllerProps, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";


export const CheckboxGroup = forwardRef(({
  control,
    label,
  options,
  onChange,

}: {
  label: string,
  options: Quality[]
  onChange: any

} & UseControllerProps<Partial<Char>>, ref:Ref<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const char = useWatch({ control }) as Char;

  let valueEntry = Object.entries(char).find(e => e[0]===label)

  let values: Quality[] = valueEntry && valueEntry[1]

    const handleChange = (value: Quality) => {
        const newArray = [ ...values ];
        const item = value;

        if (newArray.length > 0) {
            const index = newArray.findIndex(x => x === item);

            if (index === -1) {
                newArray.push(item);
            } else {
                newArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
        } else {
            newArray.push(item);
        }

        onChange(newArray);
    }

    return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={strikerTheme}>
                
                <FormGroup>
          <h5>{label}</h5>
                    {options.map((option) => (
            <Tooltip title={option.description}>
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={(values as Quality[])
                                        ?.some((checked: Quality) => checked.name === option.name)}
                                    inputRef={ref}
                                    onChange={() => handleChange(option)}
                                />}
                            label={option.name}
                            key={option.name}
                        />
            </Tooltip>

                    ))}
                </FormGroup>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
});
```

...and the call in the form that references it...

```ts
<Controller name="traits" control={control} render={({ field }) => 
  <CheckboxGroup
    control={control}
    label="traits"
    options={traits}
    {...field}
  />
} />
```

I think the crucial difference was the use of `const char = useWatch({ control }) as Char;` because this allowed me to get to the values of the field (an array of Quality). I have no idea why this was just so inaccessible the other way (I mean it must be in the control object somewhere).

The other thing is that typescript, while helpful in many areas, brings a considerable challenge when working with custom components. It took ages to figure out what types i needed to declare on things. I think [this area](https://www.react-hook-form.com/ts/) of the react-hook-form documentation needs a serious reworking, if the goal of it is to assist developers working with typescript.

So with that in mind, I'll be a little more sympathetic than they are...

In the code I have presented: the `UseControllerProps` are backed by my form data, which is of type `Char`, as I'm rarely dealing with all of it, I have used the reference `<Partial<Char>>`. The type of the option elements themselves is `Quality`, which is an array so `Quality[]`.

Hope this helps the next hapless typescript react-hook-form developer out there.